# 3 Dice rand0m variable probability

Tags: probability, random-variables, fractions, dice

Roll 3 fair six-sided dice. Let $X_1, X_2, X_3$ be the corresponding numbers.

Calculate $F_{X_1,X_2,X_3}(4, 2, 6)$.

I am confused by this problem. I assumed the answer was $\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}$, but this is wrong. The correct answer is $\frac{2}{9}$.

Comment: I assume that $F_{X_1,X_2,X_3}$ is the c.d.f of $(X_1, X_2, X_3)$, not p.m.f. as your attempt suggests.

Comment: @SangchulLee Well the question does not specify

Comment: Of course it depends on how $F_{\cdots}$ is defined, but it often denotes the cumulative distribution function (c.d.f.), which in this case is given by $$ F_{X_1,X_2,X_3}(x_1,x_2,x_3) = \mathsf{P}[X_1 \leq x_1, \ X_2 \leq x_2, \ X_3 \leq x_3]. $$ Using this interpretation we have $F_{X_1,X_2,X_3}(4,2,6) = \frac{4}{6}\times\frac{2}{6}\times\frac{6}{6} = \frac{2}{9}$. But if you have another idea, please provide both your thoughts and contexts; [*this*](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) will be a good guide for improving your guqestion.